# c# Update item in list

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have the following:

```
public class Item
{
   public Item()
   {

   }

   public string Name {get; set;}
}


public static class Extension
{
    public static Item Modify(this Item itm)
    {
        itm.Name = "Changed";

        return itm;
    }
}
```

and then in my code I instantiate a `List<Item>` and add 10 items to it.

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();  // contains 10 items
.....
```

If now I want to iterate my list and for each item I call the extension method and modify it's name property, how do I update the item in `items` list?

```
foreach (Item itm in items)
{
    Item changedItem = itm.Modify();
    // update item in items list
}
```

Comment: `foreach (Item itm in items) itm.Modify();`

Comment: your items in list are updated when u call Modify() in foreach

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. Because the `Item` is a class (reference type), it will be modified in the Items collection.

Comment: If you modify the item, you don't have to return it, it will be modified in-place as the argument. This actually also means you probably *shouldn't* return it either, as it will be confusing for the caller who expects it to return a new item and *not* modify the argument, when that is the method signature. Make the method `void Modify(this Item itm)`.

Comment: That makes sens! I don't know why I was looking for an Update() method or something like that on the List<T> itself ... of course the reference!

Comment: @DavidDury: Make `Modify` `void`. It is not a factory method and `Item` is not an immutable type like `string`. So don't return it (edit: so i agree with [Anders comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277126/c-sharp-update-item-in-list#comment46752657_29277126)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method returns the same `item` that it modifies, your `foreach` loop already does what you want.

You could produce a new list and reassign `items` for a somewhat shorter code:

```
items = items.Select(Modify).ToList();
```