# Updating Data in List

Tags: c#, list, custom-lists

I am trying to update the items in a list with user provided parameters. I am using a custom list type `AbilityScores`. See below:

```
class AbilityScores
{
    public string Strength { get; set; }
    public string Dexterity { get; set; }
    public string Constitution { get; set; }
    public string Intelligence { get; set; }
    public string Wisdom { get; set; }
    public string Charisma { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to add the update a specific part of the list:

```
if(ability == "Strength"){
            abilityScores.Where(w => w.Strength == "Strength").ToList().ForEach(s => s.Strength = scoreIncrease.ToString());
}
```

Both `ability` and `scoreIncrease` are user provided parameters. Here I am updating the strength attribute. I understand most of what I read here:

> [c# Update item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277126/c-sharp-update-item-in-list)

But I do not understand what `w => w.Strength == "Strength"` is actually doing. How would I use this in my code? I am really new to C# and lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing with this code> Are you getting any error?

Comment: `Where()` is used to find elements that match an expression. Are you really looking for elements whose `Strength` property contains the string `Strength`? If not, you don't need `Where()`.  You don't need `ToList()` or `ForEach()` to modify those elements, just use a `foreach` loop

Comment: `Where(w => w.Strength == "Strength")` is a filter statement. You get each item as an input variable (in your case it's called `w`) and you are supposed to write an anonymous function (called lambda) to return a boolean. This type of funcion is called _Predicate_.  It looks through all items of your list and will return a `IEnumerable` with only those items, that have in the property `Strength` the string value `"Strength"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `Where` at all. It is used when you want to filter somes item by a condition defined by a [Predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

In your case, you want to update the value `Strength` for all objects.

Using a `ForEach` is enough

```
foreach(var s in abilityScores)
{
    s.Strength = scoreIncrease.ToString()
}
```

Comment: The OP's code shows `s.Strength` being changed *only* if it had a value of "Strength". So if it already has a value of, say, "hello", then it must not be changed. Therefore the `Where` is required.

Answer (score 0):

`w => w.Strength == "Strength"`compares on every item in the list, whatever is property `Strength` equal to string `"Strength"`. Where function uses lambda expression for criteria which part of list you want to select.

More about lambda expression:
https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-csharp-features-5-lambda-expression

Answer (score 0):

You could try iterating over subset of your list specified by `Where`:

```
foreach(var s in abilityScores.Where(w => w.Strength == ability))
    s.Strength = scoreIncrease.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a linq statement. It does the same as the following *traditional* way:

```
if (ability == "Strength")
{
    foreach (var abilityScore in abilityScores)
    {
        if (abilityScore.Strength == "Strength")
        {
            abilityScore.Strength = scoreIncrease.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```